# How many workers should I create for a multicore CPU when using gunicorn for deployment

Tags: python, deployment, gunicorn

I'm using gunicorn for deploying my web service. And the document suggests an example configure file  in the following webpage for deploying:  http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html.

And the code is like:

```
import multiprocessing

bind = "127.0.0.1:8000"
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
```

I don't know why we should use this weird count: "num_of_cpu_core * 2 + 1". Why not just using the num of cpu cores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their [architecture page](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/design.html#how-many-workers) gives more advice on choosing the number of workers:

> While not overly scientific, the formula is based on the assumption that for a given core, one worker will be reading or writing from the socket while the other worker is processing a request.

The answer to "why not use num of cores as worker count" is that sometimes workers blocked (for example during IO operations), so having extra workers utilizes the CPU better.